# A way to access a files with javascript without using Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

So, I want to access all the mp3's in a file called music on my server. I then want to put them in a list and allow the user to play the songs. I can do this just fine using Node, but I want to be able to do this without running a server on my server. Thus I want to do this without using Node and instead using the java script I already have running. I know I can access one file using

```
$.get('music/filename.mp3', function(data){
    //var music =  $('item', data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

but when i say

```
$.get('music/*.mp3', function(data){
    //var music =  $('item', data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

it doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do this?

for referance, this is what I'm currently doing.

```
router.get('/getMusic', function(req, res, next) {
  fs.readdir('./public/music/', function(err, files) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('Sent result: ' + files);
    res.status(200).json(files);
  })
});
```

javascript

```
$.getJSON('/getMusic', function(json) {
  var options = '<option value=""></option>';
  $.each(json, function(i, item) {
    options += '<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>';
  });
  $('#songs').html(options);
})
.done(function() { console.log('getMusic getJSON request succeeded!'); })
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log('getMusic getJSON request failed! ' + textStatus);
  console.log('incoming ' + jqXHR.responseText);
})
.always(function() { console.log('getMusic getJSON request ended!');
});
```

Comment: This cannot be done "without running a server". You can do it with PHP or CGI or something else instead of Node, if you wish. The most low-level approach would be setting up Apache to list directory, then parse that page (I really don't recommend it though). `$.get('music/*.mp3', ...)` is impossible and will never work.

Comment: Javascript runs client side unless you're running node. Unless you're using some sort of server language, creating a list of the files in a directory on the server is going to be tough. You COULD provide a .js file with the filenames of the songs (which you'd have to add to when you added a song)...

The problem is that browsers don't have a mechanism (that I know of) for counting or checking what files are available in a directory on a server.

Comment: Somewhere, there is already a server that is responding to `$.get('music/filename.mp3',`.  You need to modify that server so that it supports: `$.get('music/*.mp3'` and returns the data you want.

Comment: You could generate a json file with the list of mp3's and put it as a static file on the server. You'd need to update it after adding/removing music though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere, there is already a server that is responding to:

```
$.get('music/filename.mp3?ext=mp3', ...)
```

You need to modify that server so that it supports a different URL that specifies the wildcard search you want. That other URL may either be a query parameter or a path that specifies a wildcard you want to look for and then returns the data you want:

You don't show the server-side code that already supports `$.get('music/filename.mp3',`, but that's where you start.  Create a new route that accepts a wildcard as a parameter (either as a query string or part of the request path) and then implement the wildcard behavior in that route to return the data your client wants.

For example, you might create an optional query parameter on your /getMusic route that allows you to specific an extension:

```
/* -----------------------------------------------------------
/getMusic gets all music files in the public music directory
/getMusic?ext=mp3 gets only music files with that extension
----------------------------------------------------------- */
router.get('/getMusic', function(req, res, next) {
  fs.readdir('./public/music/', function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
       res.status(500).send("fs.readdir() error");
       return;
    }

    if (req.query.ext) {
        // filter files to see if they match the extension in the query parameter
        files = files.filter(function(f) {
            return f.slice(-req.query.ext.length) === req.query.ext;
        });
    }
    console.log('Sent result: ' + files);
    res.status(200).json(files);
  })
});
```

Comment: This is some really beautiful code. This wasn't the answer I was looking for, but it's the answer I needed.

Comment: how do I make it so that I can send things like "?ext=mp3" at the end of the url?

Comment: @Beks - If it's coming from your Ajax call, you just add it onto the end of the URL you make the Ajax call to like I just added to the start of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript from the browser (which is what I assume you mean by using JavaScript without Node) can't access your file system in a way that would let it search, unlike Node.

In particular, it can't do an equivalent of your the `fs.readdir()` call in your `/getMusic` route. For that, you'd have to have Node or some other server.

If your underlying (non-Node) server (possibly nginx or Apache) is configured to search up an directory listing for the `music` directory, it's possible to read that, parse it, and then use that for your list of music. Though, that might be a bit messy.

As for actually downloading the music, you can't do wildcards. You'll have to iterate through each file directly, like you have in the first one: `$.get('music/some-file.mp3')`.

Comment: It's good to know that can't be done. Fortunately, I realized that multiple java script files can use the same node server at the same time and that fixed my problem.

Comment: Yeah. You should really think of them as separate things: the Node.js and the browser side. The server provides things to them, but they're really two separate things. The most common pattern for them nowadays is called "backend for frontend" (or BFF).